# InStr function in VBA Excel is returning 0 Even If Specified Spring Occurs in A String

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on string and getting some of it's characters that I need to copy in Excel. It works perfectly fine but when my Windows PC need to be restarted for an update and upon opening it again, the code didn't work anymore. I don't know if this has something to do with the macros being disabled or I need to configure something. Really need help for this one because it's so tiring to manually paste the details cell by cell.

```
Sub appendDetails()
    Dim jobs As String
    Dim CommandLine As String

    'Helper Variables
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    'Gets all the job description
    jobs = Cells(2, "B").Value

    If (jobs <> "") Then
     'Get CommandLine My issue is InStr(jobs, "Command Line : ") is returning 0 when in fact "Command Line : " keyword appears inside job string
     If (InStr(jobs, "Command Line : ") = 0) Then
         ActiveCell.Value = ""
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

     Else
         x = getPosition(jobs, "Command Line : ") + thisPosition("Command Line : ")
         y = getPosition(jobs, "Host/Host Group : ")
         z = getLengthOfString(x, y)
         CommandLine = getString(jobs, x, z)
         ActiveCell.Value = Trim(Replace(CommandLine, Chr(10), ""))
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
         MsgBox ("Command Line : " + CommandLine)
     End If
  End Sub
```

For clarifications, this sub function calls other functions that I haven't included here. Just if you are curious about the functions.

Comment: Really need you to provide some useful information because it's so tiring to try to figure out where the code failed, while you know where it failed, but you say nothing.

Comment: InStr is returning 0 because the specified substring is not occurring in the string. use `debug.print` to check your values

Comment: @jsotola I already updated it. That really works perfectly fine but now it keeps on returning 0 and could not return the position of "Command Line : " keyword inside job string

Comment: Yeah it'll be returning 0 once the specified substring cannot be found in a string. I'm pretty sure the substring really occur in the job string because I have use this just this morning to automate tasks but then when I restarted my PC and continue working . the code's not performing the way I want to anymore . specifically the InString

Comment: try this then:  `If (InStr(jobs, "Command Line : ",vbTextCompare) = 0) Then`

Comment: That results to type mismatch error @jsotola

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has something to do when I restart my PC

Comment: Are you sure that you are working with the correct worksheet? `Cells(2, "B").Value` reads the Cell B2 from the active sheet. Have you checked the content of the variable `jobs`? Try to debug your code with F8.

Comment: @FunThomas I now figured out the answer. When I print over the value inside jobs "Command Line : " is not written as that. There is an alt-enter (chr(10)) value after the colon sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your answer that i posted in the comments earlier

InStr is returning 0 because the specified substring is not occurring in the string. use debug.print to check your values

Comment: Yeah just because I'm pretty sure that the string really exists so I didn't check and debug at all. hehehhehhhe